# How save value of a variable in javascript after executing a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```js
var n = 0; // << I want save value of this var

$('.next').click(function () { // << after this method run   
    n++
});
function run() {
                setInterval(function () {
                    n++;
                    var slideId = '#' + "slide" + (n);
                    var dotId = '#' + "dot" + (n);

                    if (n == settings.slideNumber) {
                        n = 0;
                    }
                    var lastSlideId = '#' + "slide" + (n + 1);
                    var lastDotId = '#' + "dot" + (n + 1);

                    $(slideId).css({display: 'none'});
                    $(dotId).css({backgroundColor: '#1a1a1a'});
                    $(lastSlideId).css({display: 'block'});
                    $(lastDotId).css({backgroundColor: '#0AC986'});
                }, 2000);
            }

            run();
```

After the click event occurred  , run method will start from fist and value of n will be zero again . 
How i can save the value of n var after click event ?
( Consider that I wrote this method inside a jquery plugin )

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the click event will only increment `n` slightly faster than once every 2 seconds.

Comment: declare your variable outside the function and don't initialize it again back to zero in your function

Comment: Dear @evolutionxbox I want exactly the same thing . so when i click it should happend faster .

Comment: Dear @RAUSHAN KUMAR I know that but some how after i call run method all the script will start from fist and the value of n will become to zero

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `n` as the global variable, to keep up to date with the latest value of n.

Also, the `click` event should be outside of the `run` function, otherwise, each time you execute `run` function it will attach a new event listener for the `button click`.

I have created a sample as per your question. Hope it helps.

```js
let n = 0;

$('#btn').click(function() {
  n++;
  console.log("Value of n::",n)
});

function run() {
  console.log("Value of n::",n)
}

run();

$('#run').click(run);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click</button>

<button id="run">Run</button>
```

Comment: My real cod it's a plugin for jquery . before I post this question my code was same as you write . in your code or this problem is when i call run method js start all of plugin ( all the script ) from first so When it comes to line of n var , the value of n become zero , just like you call this method for fist time .

Comment: What is settings.slideNumber ? and where it is set ?

Comment: settings.slideNumber  is a number , number of my slides . it set at first time i call my jquery plugin as a object . if i take you the whole code have you , do you have the readiness to read it?

Comment: this is files link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8e_h_J--DuGT09MQUh6N3JlOWs . the story is that i,m working on a plugin that you take a div to it , with some information as object and it build a slider for you .
the slider works but arrow keys don't .  Because of the same problem I mentioned. look that can you make the keys work?